# java.io.IOException: Invalid argument (sendto failed) Jboss 5.1.0.GA

Tags: jboss, ejb, jndi, jboss5.x

I am getting following exception in jboss 5.1.0.GA. I have configured messaging queues in it. That setup is working correctly, but in logs i see following exception.

---

```
**
> java.io.IOException: Invalid argument (sendto failed)         at
> java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)         at
> java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:696)         at
> org.jboss.ha.jndi.DetachedHANamingService$DiscoveryRequestHandler.run(DetachedHANamingService.java:786)
> at
> org.jboss.util.threadpool.RunnableTaskWrapper.run(RunnableTaskWrapper.java:147)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 02/14 03:45:00 Error writing
> response(ERROR)
**
```

---

Comment: This problem is related to a JNDI lookup, not JMS.

Comment: Can you share more details what i need to check for?

Comment: A `java.net.DatagramSocket` is used to send UDP multicast traffic so you could investigate the failure from that angle. It's worth noting that JBoss AS 5.1.0 is very old and so you're not likely to get much help for it at this point (especially if you find a bug).